# How to use string as a object method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use an element class name and call it as a method for my object.

```
 var thisClass=$this.attr('class')
 //thisClass = 'call'               

 obj.thisClass(ID);
```

My codes don't work as I wanted to be. Are there anyways to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: array-access notation: `obj[thisClass](ID)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
obj[methodName](arguments, ...);
```

This works because functions are objects as well in javascript and are themselves only attributes of their objects. Object properties can be accessed with the . and the [] notation whereas the [] notations is needed for dynamic names or names that are not legal javascript identifiers.

Comment: Whether to use dot or bracket notation can be explained as: dot notation can only be used for property names that are valid [identifiers](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6), square bracket notation must be used for everything else (expressions, string literals, numbers, etc.). E.g. numeric array members are accessed as `arr[0]` and not `arr.0` because `0` is not a valid identifier.